# Сannot set a property in a test

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I run the test gives an error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'background' of undefined

```
   6 | componentDidMount() {
   7 |     const element = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)
>  8 |     element.style.background = 'grey'
     |     ^
   9 |   }
```

code component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class Test extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const element = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)
    element.style.background = 'grey'
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Test">
        test
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

code tests:

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from './Test';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer
    .create(<Test/>)
    .toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

This is a fairly simple component, and as I understand the jest cannot reach the DOM, how do I fix this problem? The simplest thing is that I thought of doing this as:

> element.style && (element.style.background = 'gray')

Comment: Does it work if you [use a `ref` in your component instead](https://codesandbox.io/s/96njq2w6p)?

Comment: the component works as it should the problem in the test itself

Comment: Yes, I understand, but do you get a different test result if you try a `ref`?

Comment: This example is exceedingly arbitrary. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, note that the `ReactDOM.findDOMNode` [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode) states:

> `findDOMNode` is an escape hatch used to access the underlying DOM node. In most cases, use of this escape hatch is discouraged because it pierces the component abstraction. It has been deprecated in `StrictMode`.

So use of `findDOMNode` is to be avoided and using a `ref` is preferred.

---

Having said that, the reason why the test fails is because you are using `react-test-renderer`.

The [overview in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html#overview) states that `react-test-renderer`...

> ...makes it easy to grab a snapshot of the platform view hierarchy (similar to a DOM tree) rendered by a React DOM or React Native component without using a browser or `jsdom`.

In other words, `react-test-renderer` gives a "platform view hierarchy" *similar to a DOM tree*, but does not provide an actual DOM tree (or simulated DOM tree like `jsdom`).

So in this case `element` *is not actually a DOM element* and does not contain a definition for `style` which causes `element.style.background` to throw an error.

---

To test this code as written you would need to use something that renders to a DOM tree (or simulated DOM tree).

One of the most common ways to do that is to use `mount` from [Enzyme](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html) which does a full DOM rendering using a simulated DOM provided by `jsdom`:

```
import React from 'react';
import Test from './Test';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<Test />);  // renders successfully
  ...
});
```